# jquery autocomplete unexpected token <

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, laravel, autocomplete

So recently I make a laravel project with autocomplete using jQuery Autocomplete by Devbridge. I tried to get suggestion from database but it didn't show anything.

Google Chrome console shows "SyntaxError: Unexpected Token < on jquery.autocomplete.js:85"
Mozilla Firefox console shows "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character on jquery.autocomplete.js:85" and also a warning " empty string passed to getElementById() on jquery-2.0.2.js:151"

Both error points to last line of function Autocomplete()

```
transformResult: function (response) {
   return typeof response === 'string' ? $.parseJSON(response) : response;
}
```

Here is my text input in bladeview (transaksi/add):

```
 {{Form::open(array('action' => 'TransactionController@store', 'role' => 'form'))}}
 <div class="box-body">
   <div class="form-group">
     {{Form::hidden('kode_acc')}}
     {{Form::label('kode', 'Kode Account') }}
     {{Form::text('kode', '', array('class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'kode'))}}
   </div>
///some other inputs
 {{ Form::close() }}
```

Routes:

```
//route autocomplete kode account
 Route::get('transaksi/getAccountsAutocomplete',array('uses'=>'AccountController@getAccountsAutocomplete'));
```

Controller

```
public function getAccountsAutocomplete(){
    $term = Input::get('kode');
    $suggestions = array();
    $search = DB::query("SELECT * 
                FROM  `accounts` 
                WHERE  `nama` LIKE  '%".$term."%')";
    foreach($search as $results => $account){
        $suggestions[] = array('id'=>$account->id,
                            'nama'=>$account->nama,
                            'value'=>$account->id);
    }
    return Response::json($suggestions);
}
```

jQuery script

```
 $(function(){
  $('#kode').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{URL('/getAccountsAutocomplete')}}",
            data: {
                kode: request.term
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("[SUCCESS] " + data.length + " item(s)");
                response(data);
            },
        });
    },
    select: function(event, ui){
        $('#kode_acc').val(ui.item.id);
    }
  });
 });
```

-- update --

Additional information

From Chrome Network, I just found out that the query goes to

```
transaksi/add?query=
```

when it actually should go to

```
transaksi/getAccountsAutocomplete
```

to reach the Controller.

I'm quite new with jQuery and Laravel. Any help to this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the server you are sending a JSON header, so, in your jvascript file you could do:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "{{URL('/getAccountsAutocomplete')}}",
        dataType, "json",
        data: {
            kode: request.term
        },
        success: function (data) {
            // "data" es a json object. No need convert it
        },
    });
```

See the attribute `dataType` that specifies the kind of data expecting from server. However, you should debug your function in order to verify what kind of data you are converting:

```
transformResult: function (response) {
   console.log(response);
   return typeof response === 'string' ? $.parseJSON(response) : response;
}
```

### Edit 1

In order to debug your route (maybe the Javascript ajax url is not finding the correct controller)  you could do this:

```
// temporarily disable it
//return Response::json($suggestions);


// try to return a test json object 
return Response::json("controller found");
```

In your response still printing html characters then the controllers is not routed correctly

### Edit 2

In javascript code, you are not allowed to put php code as you did:

```
url: "{{URL('/getAccountsAutocomplete')}}",
```

A good way to achive this, is to create a global javascript variable in your head section (must be the placed before any javascript script).

```
<script>
    var my_app_url = '<?php echo Url::to("/")?>';   
</script>
```

Then, you can do ajax request using this url like:

```
$.ajax({
        url: my_app_url + "/getAccountsAutocomplete",
        dataType, "json",
        data: {
            kode: request.term
        },
        success: function (data) {
            // "data" es a json object. No need convert it
        },
    });
```

Then, your ajax request should find your controller

Comment: So the response is a HTML begins with "<!DOCTYPE html>" that's why it shows "unexpected token < ".. any idea how to get only the array of suggestions?

Comment: See edited post.  (in my country is 2am), so,  i go to sleep and come in  a couple of hours

Comment: It didn't find the correct controller. I just noticed that the query goes to "transaksi/add?query=" when it should go to "transaksi/getAccountsAutocomplete/"